# Extracting a nested tuples from list (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a list that has nested tuples.

```
nested = [['53062423-690f-4923-8f65-db710c038566', [('12253996-b2f7-46c7-b49f-09ca87cac84f', 'AFC_PoCv1.0'), ('b17bd025-611f-4728-9396-e59388ee59f6', 'Customer Profitability Sample'), ('b4a5d199-2c6f-4f8d-9fcb-5e4971254f73', 'Jammers vs Floaty Pants')]], ['988f64ea-14b2-4ad7-a899-ae40974c9139', [('9137e0f9-4063-479a-baff-8566c91302ff', 'DailySalesDashboard13Azure')]]]
```

I want to flatten the list into a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nested, columns =('id', 'This column of tuples needs to split into two'))
df
```

results in,

[image]

but doesn't split the tuples into two columns with one tuple per row (with the associated id as the 3rd column).  Feels like a simple list comprehension- but I have come up blank.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do `explode`

```
s = pd.DataFrame(nested,columns=['c1','c2']).explode('c2').reset_index(drop=True)
# if only need to split the tuple , you do not need to do the next steps
```

---

Split the tuple into single columns

```
s = s.join(pd.DataFrame(s['c2'].tolist()))
s
Out[162]: 
                                     c1  ...                              1
0  53062423-690f-4923-8f65-db710c038566  ...                    AFC_PoCv1.0
1  53062423-690f-4923-8f65-db710c038566  ...  Customer Profitability Sample
2  53062423-690f-4923-8f65-db710c038566  ...        Jammers vs Floaty Pants
3  988f64ea-14b2-4ad7-a899-ae40974c9139  ...     DailySalesDashboard13Azure
[4 rows x 4 columns]
```